C++: CMake / Visual Studio failing to link external libraries when called from header, but works when called from .cpp
I'm trying to write a library that works as an interface between E57Format and the rest of our projects and include that as a subdirectory in my main CMake. When I call functions of the E57Format from a linked .cpp file of that subdirectory, it works fine. But as soon as I call a function from the .hpp file in the subdirectory, the linker fails to find those. Of course, I want to create a template function, so I need those calls in my .hpp. Funnily enough, it works when I create my library using STATIC instead of SHARED, and while that works for now I'd like to stay as versatile as possible and also understand the error. Here are my code snippets:
Main CMake:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("e57test" LANGUAGES CXX )


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} 
    "src/main.cpp"
)


# Find Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

# VTK
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include("${VTK_USE_FILE}")
include_directories(${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

# PCL
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS io octree visualization filters segmentation registration)
include_directories( ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE VTK_LEGACY_SILENT -DNO_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATIONS)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PCL_COMPILE_OPTIONS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_DEFINITIONS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})


# E57Wrapper
add_subdirectory("e57wrapper")
get_target_property(LIBB_INCLUDES e57wrapper INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE e57wrapper)


target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

with main.cpp just calling my function in the subdirectory ("e57wrapper"):
#include "e57wrapper/E57Wrapper.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo();
}

and here's my subdirectory's CMake:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
endif()

project (e57wrapper LANGUAGES CXX )

add_library(e57wrapper SHARED
    "E57Wrapper.cpp"
)

# PCL
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE VTK_LEGACY_SILENT -DNO_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATIONS)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PCL_COMPILE_OPTIONS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_DEFINITIONS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})


# e57Format
find_package( E57Format CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE E57Format)


target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Output .dll to built .exe location
set_target_properties(e57wrapper PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)

with the E57Wrapper.cpp:
#include "E57Wrapper.hpp"

//other functions

and E57Wrapper.hpp:
#pragma once

#include <E57Format/E57Version.h>
#include <E57Format/E57SimpleData.h>
#include <E57Format/E57SimpleWriter.h>

//other functions

inline void foo()
{
    e57::RigidBodyTransform a = e57::RigidBodyTransform(); // Fails to link
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << a.rotation.w << "\n";
}

I've already tried adding the .hpp file to add_library, both before and after my .cpp but without any luck. I don't think it is needed since .cpp includes it anyway?
Here's also the exact Linker error output, in case that's unclear:
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl e57::RigidBodyTransform::RigidBodyTransform(void)" (__imp_??0RigidBodyTransform@e57@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?test@@YAXXZ)  C:\prog\e57test\out\build\x64-release\e57test   C:\prog\e57test\out\build\x64-release\e57test.cpp.obj   1       

Hope anyone has an idea what could be causing this behavior.

The error says it expects to link to an import library for e57 that goes with a dll that will be needed at runtime.

Oh yeah, you're right. My subdirectory's CMake actually output's its .dll to the folder where the .exe is built, so the linker probably can't find it. But removing that line of code also fails to link. How should I specify subdirectory's output s.t. they're found by the linker?

Template functions don't compile down into actual code unless you have actual calls in that linker unit with the proper template parameters filled in.

With msvc in standard c++ the liker doesn't use the dll for linking other projects instead it needs an import library which will have a .lib extension and go with the dll. If your dll doesn't export any symbols the .lib is not created when you build the dll. This import library although it has a .lib extension just will have stubs for the implemented functions which can be found in the dll.
